# Atmospheric carbon removal: asphalt from CO2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, environmental-chemistry

In reading a text about $\ce{CO2}$ recycling and sequestration of various kinds, I came to think about storing atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ as asphalt. Given cheap energy as in the case of Iceland, and improved atmospheric carbon capture technologies, could this be feasible? Is there a name for the reverse cracking process?

Comment: Organic revers process to cracking is called Photosynthesis.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of building very long carbon chains, that's not photosynthesis, is it? Photosynthesis would just be the first step, right?

Comment: An alternative to photosynthesis will be great breakthrough.

Comment: Reducing CO2 back to alkanes (not neseserily using light energy) isn't viable as we're burning fuel to get energy - so what one country would be producing energy and the other losing it to reverse it?

Comment: Trading in negative emissions would make carbon removal itself a business, under cap- and trade systems. Under carbon tax systems the tax could be made symmetric around zero, so that removal is subsidized by the same amount that an emission of the same size would cost. Energy for the process might come from nuclear or renewables.

Comment: See this article http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/08/150819083117.htm
They have an aike idea.

Comment: I just realized the word I was looking for is polymerization.